# Create dynamic URLs in Flask with url_for()

Tags: python, flask

Half of my Flask routes requires a variable say, `/<variable>/add` or `/<variable>/remove`. How do I create links to those locations?

`url_for()` takes one argument for the function to route to but I can't add arguments?

Answer (score 398, accepted):

It takes keyword arguments for the variables:

```
url_for('add', variable=foo)
url_for('remove', variable=foo)
```

The flask-server would have functions:

```
@app.route('/<variable>/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add(variable):

@app.route('/<variable>/remove', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def remove(variable):
```

Comment: But the problem is how 'foo' is beyond the scope if it's a variable from Python. Then, how do you solve it?

Comment: Just so that it is clearer, if you have `@app.route("/<a>/<b>")` and `def function(a,b): ...` as its function, then you should use `url_for` and specify its keyword arguments like this: `url_for('function', a='somevalue', b='anothervalue')`

Comment: This is also explained in the quickstart: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/?highlight=url_for#url-building

Answer (score 181):

`url_for` in Flask is used for creating a URL to prevent the overhead of having to change URLs throughout an application (including in templates). Without `url_for`, if there is a change in the root URL of your app then you have to change it in every page where the link is present.

Syntax: `url_for('name of the function of the route','parameters (if required)')`

It can be used as:

```py
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'you are in the index page'
```

Now if you have a link the index page:you can use this:

```html
<a href={{ url_for('index') }}>Index</a>
```

You can do a lot o stuff with it, for example:

```py
# int has been used as a filter so that only integer can be passed in the url, otherwise it will give a 404 error
@app.route('/questions/<int:question_id>')
def find_question(question_id):  
    return ('you asked for question{0}'.format(question_id))
```

For the above we can use:

```html
<a href = {{ url_for('find_question' ,question_id=1) }}>Question 1</a>
```

Like this you can simply pass the parameters!

Comment: I have a question, in the first example, the index method was passed as a string while in the second method, the find_question is being passed as variable. Why?

Comment: @AnandTyagi Is this what you mean? [URL routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#url-building)

Comment: @आनंद if variable you do: `{{ url_for('find_question' ,question_id=question.id) }}` and not `{{ url_for('find_question' ,question_id={{question.id}}) }}`

Comment: how to hash the int parameter?

Answer (score 52):

Refer to [the Flask API document for `flask.url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for)

Other sample snippets of usage for linking js or css to your template are below.

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 23):

**Templates:**

Pass function name and argument.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('get_blog_post',id = blog.id)}}">{{blog.title}}</a>
```

**View,function**

```
@app.route('/blog/post/<string:id>',methods=['GET'])
def get_blog_post(id):
    return id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add function means that the page you want to render that function whould be added inside the url_for(function name).
It will redirect to that function and the page will render accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, you can override the static folder when declaring your flask app.

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder='/path/to/static',
            template_folder='/path/to/templates')
```