# How to read images from directory, assemble them in <img src="">, and have flask return image?

Tags: python, flask

I have a directory full of images.  In one of my templates, I want to display these images

GET template:

```
render_template("registration.html", images=images)
```

in template: (using image/{{image}} because url_for doesn't accept variables)

```
{% for image in images %}
    <input  class="avatar" type = "radio" name = "avatar" value = "{{image}}"/><img src = "image/{{image}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

and in app.py

```
@app.route('/images/<image>')
def images(image):
    return send_file('public/assets/thumbs'+image, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

(public/assets/thumbs is the directory images reside in) however, this fails completely.  Is there any tricks or hacks I can use to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: send_from_directory()

```
@app.route("/image/<image>", methods=["GET"])
def image(image):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'assets/thumbs/' + image, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it could help you neither if the method i'll describe is good practice but to display images from directory (using send_from_directory in my view as described below by Andrew Allbright) in templates I was using :

```
{% for image in images %}
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='image/')}}{{image}}"></img>
{% endfor %}
```

I remember I took inspiration from this SO post: [Create dynamic URLs in Flask with url_for()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478366/create-dynamic-urls-in-flask-with-url-for) (second answer) that indicates you can pass argument to url_for() in your templates.

Comment: Have you verified that this works?  Right now, my directory method sucks when the directory is full of .jpg, .jpeg, .png image files :)

Edit: I suppose I'll check myself.  I have a module that needs images and I think I'll try this out.  Fingers crossed it just works :D