# TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, flask

If x=ohio

I want to redirect the user to /weather/ohio

All I have been able to get to work is /weather/?x=ohio

I am doing this so a second route  @app.route("/weather/")  will be run.  I am not sure what I am missing.  IS this the best way to load /weather/ohio, where ohio is a variable loaded from a form.

```
    @app.route("/weather/", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def weather():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.form['search_location']
        return redirect(url_for('weather', x=x))
        #print (y)
    else:
        return render_template("weather.html")
```

If I take the x= out I get the error "TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: If any of the answers helped, consider marking it as such, so that others with the same problem can find the solution as well

Comment: Turns out the issue was that the issue was that return redirect(url_for('weather', x=x)) was pointing to the wrong function it was suppose to be weathers NOT weather.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the second endpoint with a path variable and give `url_for()` the name of the function associated with the endpoint:

```py
@app.route("/weather", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def weather():
    if request.method == "POST":
        x = request.form["search_location"]
        return redirect(url_for("weather_location", x=x))
    else:
        return render_template("weather.html")

@app.route("/weather/<x>")
def weather_location(x):
    return "It's always sunny in {}".format(x)
```

Take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478366/create-dynamic-urls-in-flask-with-url-for) for maybe a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

It takes keyword arguments for the variables:

```
url_for('add', variable=x)
```

Comment: The problem is that using your example the url becomes http://127.0.0.1:5000/weather/?variable=ohio
when I need
http://127.0.0.1:5000/weather/ohio

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you want a dynamic route?

Have a look here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_variable_rules.htm

```
@app.route("/weather/<variable>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
```

Comment: I have a from that I fill out <form-data> and I want the form data to be passed into the url as /weather/<form-data>  so if ohio is entered into the form I want  /weather/ohio to be redirect to.

Comment: from that form, pass the variable you need to the route I just showed you, and then pass that to your function. Check out the tutorial I have linked, and read the flask documentation, which does a really good job of explaining this

Comment: I do not see any examples of variables in redirect(url_for