# Flask routing and relative paths

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am making a website using Flask. It's utilizing a base template in HTML, which is used for all pages. In the base page (called `base.html`) there is some references to various static files. The references are using relative paths.

Here is a couple of examples from `base.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">
```

This works fine, as long as I don't include input parameters in my route, but rather get them from requests like this:

```
@app.route('/person/delete')
def delete_person():
    id = request.args.get('id')
    # some more logic here...
```

However, if I change my route to include the input parameters, like this:

```
@app.route('/person/delete/<int:id>')
def delete_person(id):
    # some more logic here...
```

Then my relative path will fail. It seems that I am one level to deep, in  the latter example. At least I get the following error in the log:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2019 19:20:14] "GET /person/static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - 
>   127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2019 19:20:14] "GET /person/static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

The `person` part should not be a part of the URL, as the `static` folder is in the root level. Is there some clever way to counter this behavior?

**Note:** I could probably avoid relative paths in the `base.html` file and simply use some sort of shortcut to the base folder, but that would potentially mean that I can never use relative paths. That would be quite sad.

Comment: You need to use `url_for`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dynamic URLs in Flask with url\_for()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478366/create-dynamic-urls-in-flask-with-url-for)

Comment: `../static` seems wrong to me, it wouldn't be `/static` ?

Comment: @roganjosh I though `url_for()` was just an alternative to a string url (similar to `nameof()` in C#). Does it behave differently than writing the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `url_for` is the proper solution.

An example from other project:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='nnn.min.css') }}">
```

In general, `url_for` cannot be replaced by hardcoded URLs, not even absolute ones, because the whole Flask application may be deployed with a prefix in its base URL, e.g. `https://www.example.com/appname`. The `appname` is a part of the configuration and it is known only at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that instead of a relative path. If anyone else, like me, should struggle with subfolders, they go in front of the file name :-).