# App Route Not Working When I Specify URL (Python Flask)

Tags: python, flask

When I don't specify the URL it returns doctor_results as I had expected.
[image]

But when I change it by adding [image]

It also renders doctor.html but doesn't return doctor_results.html unlike when the route is '/'. Instead, it gives me an error of `Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`  and the url returns to localhost:5000

The POST in doctor.html looks like this:
[image]

Comment: "It doesn't work" can mean many things. What are you seeing that you don't expect to, or what aren't you seeing that you expect?

Comment: What is the caller’s route in your HTML?  Looks like the `/Medical` caller is sending a GET request; which is why I’m curious to see the HTML snippet.

Comment: Have you changed the second method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `<form method='POST' action='/'>` to `<form method='POST' action='/Medical'>` should work.

Action attribute specifies the route that handles the form inputs when you click submit. Although you changed app route from '/' to '/Medical', the html file still looks for '/' when you click submit, but now that you have changed that route in flask and '/' route doesn't exist anymore, so it returns "Not Found".

Comment: @JoyGarcia - And better yet, use `url_for(‘index’)`. [Here is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936261/6340496).