# Flask, Jinja2 and Python, get URL dynamically from dictionary

Tags: python, flask

I have a dictionary with two dictionaries inside, with key-value pairs. I am trying to get the URL dynamically so that, when I display a bulletlist of dict names, I click them and I get a page with the related key-value pairs. So that suppose I have

```
cities = { 'Moskow': {'Russia':'RU'}, 'London': {'United Kingdom':'UK'}
```

On the index.html page is displayed:

- Moskow
- London

I click on Moskow and I get

- Russia, RU

But when I click on London I get

- United Kingdom, UK

I tried using url_for in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cities</h1>
<ul>
        {% for city, city_info in cities.items(): %}
    <li><a href={{url_for({{city}})}}>{{city}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And route is

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    citydict = cities
    return render_template('index.html', title='Welcome', cities=citydict)
    
    @app.route('/city')
    def city():
        citydict = cities
        return render_template('cities.html', title='Welcome', cities=citydict)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Show your route. I guess you pass city name as parameter, right? Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/7478366/4046632

Comment: Edited... I tried that way but I don't really understand how it could work

Comment: first of all, your spacing of the second function is wrong. It should be on the same level as index

Comment: Saw that, it was right in the code but it was messed up during the formatting phase on here

Answer (score -1):

Edited

It won't work because you don't have any defined functions named  "Moskow" or "London".

By your logic, your html file will have something like - `url_for('Moskow')` and `url_for('London')` but you don't have any routes or anything like `define Moskow()` or `define London()`

Updated:

See this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936261/15211203) for how to use url_for

Comment: I want them to be added dynamically though, because what if you have 100 dict names?