# Passing a variable with return redirect(url_for())

Tags: python, flask

I have a login page that pulls the credentials from the form then uses those credentials in an API to get an authorization token. I am trying to pass that token to the /home URL to use it in other API calls but instead of passing the variable it adds it to the /home URL instead:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/home?headers=%7B%27Accept%27%3A+%27application%2Fjson%27,+%27X-AUTH-TOKEN%27%3A+%27VUw2U89iobifuyfaieubsifhoi%27%7D


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = {"username": request.form['username'], "password": request.form['password']}
        response = requests.post("https://api.com/v2/authorize", json=query)
        x = json.loads(response.text)
        if response.status_code==201:
            headers = {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-AUTH-TOKEN': x["authToken"]
            }
            return redirect(url_for('registered', headers=headers))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route("/home", methods=['GET','POST'])
def registered(headers):
    return render_template('registered.html')
```

Is the syntax incorrect for passing this parameter or do I need to use a different method of passing it?

Comment: Almost. Your "/home" route should be configured like so: `@app.route("/home/<headers>", ...)` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7478366/15368978) for more details on calling and receiving variables with `url_for`.

Comment: That did not work I changed the route to @app.route("/home/<headers>", methods=['GET','POST']) and now I get this error: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Strange, would you mind updating the question to include the full error traceback?