# Why does my flask route show 404, after trying to link it into my starting page

Tags: python, html, flask, cs50

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytUXw.png)[

```
    @app.route("/search")
    def search():
        return render_template("/search.html")
][1]
```

[How my search route appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yNKN.png)

This the code used in my app.py.
I have tried

{href="./search.html"}

but there is no difference.

Edit
[How my project folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsqBj.png)
Edit 2:
[My mistake in the routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytUXw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

to link your routes from within your HTML pages, you can use the `url_for` function inside double curly brackets. so in your case it would be something like this:

`<a href="{{url_for('search')}}">Search Page</a>`

note that the value you pass into `url_for` is the name of the function for your route, not the route itself.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936261/19373112) for more info.

Comment: Hello, I've tried that too. Seems that im still receiving a 404 error. I've added another picture to show how my folder looks like

Comment: is this the only route behaving this way?

Comment: No, all my routes seem to act this way.

Comment: @s0ulzz it may be worth looking at the docs and starting from scratch to help find out where you went wrong.

Comment: Just tested. I think there might be an issue with me not using a route?? I've tried to do it without a route so far, and im not certain how to work around that issue. I've added another picture for reference.

Comment: oh, I think I misunderstood your original question. you are asking how to link between your routes/pages in HTML. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend! I can finally move to construct the other parts of my project. So sorry for not providing a clearer understanding of my question earlier!